# c# task multi-queue throttling

Tags: c#, queue, task-parallel-library, task

I need a environment which needs to maintain different task queues, and for each of them to have a well defined number of concurrent threads that can execute for each queue. Something like this:

- Queue 1 -> 3 threads;
- Queue 2 -> 6 threads;

Kind of Task system. I have managed to implement by myself this using plain old c# code (aka System.Threading.Thread, lock and queue) which works more than fine for 1+ year. However, I keep reading articles about the wonders of TaskFactory and TaskScheduler, about being possible this things with built-in classes in .NET, but I have failed to find an example to prove this. I would like to test it and to compare with what I have right now to see if it's working better and if it does, to replace it.

More, I can live without having to limit/set the number of parallel threads for each queue as long as I can get the `guarantee` that if an item targeted for queue #2 is executed imediatly even if queue #1 is executing on full load.

So, my question is - is there something in .net 4 and more, can someone point me to a sample? I am looking for one an entire week and failed to get something relevant.

Answer (score 8):

This is actually pretty trivial using the [TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) and the new collections in [`System.Collections.Concurrent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx).

For your needs the [`BlockingCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287223.aspx) is what I would recommend. By default it uses a [`ConcurrentQueue<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx) as the underlying store which is perfect for what you want.

```
var queue = new BlockingCollection<Message>();
```

To set some code working on those messages, and control how many can execute in parallel is as simple as this:

```
//Set max parallel Tasks
var options = new ParallelOptions
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10
};

Parallel.ForEach(queue.GetConsumingEnumerable(), options, msg =>
{
    //Do some stuff with this message
});
```

So what is going on here? Well...

The call to [`GetConsumingEnumerable()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287186.aspx) will actually block until there is something in `queue` to consume. This is great because no extra code is necessary for signaling that new work is ready to be done. Rather, as `queue` fills up, a new Task with your *(anonymous)* delegate will be kicked off with an item.

The [`ParallelOptions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.aspx) object allows you to control how [`Parallel.ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach.aspx) operates. In this case, you are telling it you never want more than 10 Tasks executing at any one time. **It is important to note that Tasks != Threads**. The details are murky, but needless to say there is a lot of optimization going on under the hood. It's all pluggable mind you, but that is not for the faint of heart.

There are obviously a lot of details I haven't covered here, but hopefully you can see how simple and expressive using the Task Parallel Library can be.

Comment: The OP seems to need a priority queue and priority threads to execute the items on queue#2 first.

Comment: That is not the impression I got. He simply indicated he need to be able to control the number of concurrent tasks so that no one Queue eats up all the resources. The solution above can easily be extended by having multiple Queues. Filling those queues is up to him, but it is pretty easy to control how many tasks can execute in parallel this way. One with 50, another with 10, etc...